# Android horizontalscrollview center lock

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

How can we implement center-locking while scrolling with a horizontalscrollview

I already saw this
http://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/tag/horizontal-scrollview-with-auto-center-lock/
but it's not what I need, I need auto center-lock

I have a scrollview with 3 different layouts(1st: whole width, 2nd: whole width, 3rd: half screen) , also I tried with gallery but I can't remove the space at the left and right side,

thank you

Comment: What you mean by center-locking?

Comment: it's like the gallery, when you scroll it, it always end up centering the item that is closest to the center of the screen

Answer (score 1):

An example for pretty much what you are looking for:
http://www.velir.com/blog/index.php/2010/11/17/android-snapping-horizontal-scroll/

It's explained quite nicely in my opinion, so you should be able to tailor it to your use case.

BUT: The constant SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY is set too high. 50 worked in my case. Simply try around until you're satisfied.

Edit:
Alternatively, you might want to use a ViewPager. It's probably easier and better fits the "gallery" use case.

Comment: Don't we have to create a fragment for each item?

Comment: When using a ViewPager, yes, otherwise no. Just consider which option suits your needs better. For example, HorizontalScrollView would allow the user to scroll through several items with a single swipe, but is more difficult to implement nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Java:

```
    horizontalScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                        int horizontalWidth = v.getMeasuredWidth();
                        int horizontalHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
                        int centerX = v.getScrollX() + horizontalWidth / 2;
                        int centerY = horizontalHeight / 2;
                        Rect hitRect = new Rect();
                        for (int i = 0; i < horizontalContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
                            View child = horizontalContainer.getChildAt(i);
                            child.getHitRect(hitRect);
                            if (hitRect.contains(centerX, centerY)) {
                                int x = (child.getLeft() - (horizontalWidth / 2)) + (child.getWidth() / 2);
                                horizontalScrollView.smoothScrollTo(x, 0);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Where xml is:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/horizontalContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The container is might contain by the syubykh of children, with any sizes